# Ranking with Pivot table Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007, pivot-table

I use excel 2007. I have a pivot table with values 'Brands'- Brand Names and the 'Sales' figure of each brand in another column. I want to rank the brands by ascending order of 'Sales'. I do this using 'RANK' function.

But I heard that we can do this using pivot table itself.  [MS Office blog](http://blogs.office.com/2010/11/02/add-rank-to-pivottable/) says how to do this. [Please go through the link].

I did till assigning a value of 1 to new 'calculated field' correctly. But I fail in getting correct result after setting "Running Total In" ('Sales') in the 'Value Field Settings' > 'Show Values As' tab. I get `#N/A` in each rows where the ranks are expected.

Could any master minds help me to sort this out.. I would be grateful since it will help me in my day to day work.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Select "Running Total In" ('Brands'), as you want to rank the Brands. It works perfectly.